# How to create and integrate a Presale in a web

Tags: spl-token, token-sale-program

I'm trying to create a new token and want to learn more about Solana token program.
My goal is to create a pre-sale and implement in on web, but I couldn't find enough YouTube videos.

Can anyone share some resources, links, documentations or videos for a detailed guide on it?